# [Microsoft][Hardy] (34) Error from server: SSL_connect: wrong version number

Tags: windows, hive, odbc, hadoop2

Unable to test the HiveODBC driver's System DSN [image: setup].

The error shown is
[image: SSL_Connect error]

Comment: have you found any solution